# how to get jQuery attr selector in lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make jQuery attr selector in lowercase, below is my code which raise an error (because of href.toLowerCase), what is the correct way, TIA.

```
 var url = window.location.href; 
     $("ul.menu-content li a[href.toLowerCase()='" + url.toLowerCase() + "']).each(function () {
     code....
     });
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a quote here `url.toLowerCase() + "']).each(` ==> `url.toLowerCase() + "']").each(` and why do you have `href.toLowerCase()` ?

Comment: yes @Romain sorry I missed that quote..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to filter after the fact, you can't do this in a selector:

```
var url = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
$("ul.menu-content li a[href]").filter(function() {
    return this.href.toLowerCase() == url;
}).each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Note that I used the `href` **property**, not attribute, since you're comparing with `window.location.href` and presumably want to test the *resolved* URL, not the possibly-relative one in the `href` attribute.

**Note**: If you're reading this in (say) 2019 or later or you only need to support Chrome and Firefox, see [Zenoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48904299/157247): CSS is getting a case-insensitive flag.

Comment: can we get to know if none of anchor has that href ?

Comment: @SunilKumar: You can check `length` on the jQuery object returned by `filter` (it's also returned by `each`). If the `length` is 0, none matched.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure you'll get a notification for my comment on my answer, so I'm pinging you here ^^

Answer (score 1):

On cutting-edge browsers (see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-case-insensitive), currently Chrome and Firefox, not Edge or IE), you could use the [case insensitive equality modifier `i`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-case) that's currently in the latest draft spec:

```
$("ul.menu-content li a[href='" + url + "'i]")
```

```js
console.log($('div[data-test="insensitive"i]').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-test="iNsEnSiTiVe">Test !</div>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's a jQuery thing, but I can't seem to find the doc again, let me check.

Comment: @SunilKumar Works fine with me. Try removeing the space before the `i`, I added that by mistake.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added a space by mistake in the first version of my answer, seems like it was the problem here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did some digging and it's apparently similar the the case insensitive flag from RegEx.

Comment: @Zenoo: It's not a jQuery thing; [check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/jawqbe7o/). Works with `querySelector` on Chrome and Firefox, fails (including in jQuery) in Edge and IE11. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-case-insensitive) has it: It's [in the process of being standardized](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-case)! Very interesting! I've taken the liberty of editing that info into the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the info !

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just a little update on things: MDN now lists it in its [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) page.